# LastUpdatedDate in ODS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, hana

I am migrating data from SAP HANA view to ODS (Azure Data Factory). From there, the other third-party company is moving data to Salesforce database. Now, when I migrate it we are doing a truncate and load in sink.

There is no column in source which shows the date or last updated date when the news rows are added in SAP HANA.

Do we need to have the date in the source, or any other way we can write it in ODS?

It must show with a last updated date or something to denote when a row has been inserted or changed after initial load. So that they have a track when loading onto Salesforce database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate and Load a staging table, then run a stored procedure to [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) into your target table, marking inserted and updated rows with the current sysdatetime().  Or MERGE from the staging table into a [Temporal Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017), or a table with [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) enabled to track the changes automatically.